# BitmapFactory.decodeStream with inJustDecodeBounds=true always return 100x100

Tags: android, bitmap

This is my android code:

```java
InputStream input = getAssets().open("photo.jpg");
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);
System.out.println("### img size: " + options.outWidth + "x" + options.outHeight);
```

But I found no matter how big of my image, it always print:

```
### img size: 100x100
```

Where is wrong?

---

**UPDATE**

It works fine after I re-deploying my application, but I modified nothing. It's strange but I want to keep this question here, maybe it will appear someday again.

Comment: InputStream input=????????????

Comment: Where do you test this? On a phone or emulator?

Comment: On my android pad. I don't know why it's fine now after re-deploying my app -- I modified nothing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//Read Bitmap Dimensions and Type

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

[Ref here:](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap)

//you didn't assigned object name

```
InputStream input = getAssets().open("photo.jpg");
```

The BitmapFactory class provides several decoding methods `(decodeByteArray(), decodeFile(), decodeResource()`, etc.) for creating a Bitmap from various sources.

Comment: Sorry, there is no `resource` here, it's just a stream.